# Remove all characters from string after the first digit with the least amount of code

Tags: python

So far, to remove all characters from a string after the first digit, I came up with

```
import re
s1 = "thishasadigit4here"
m = re.search(r"\d", s1)
result = s1[:m.start()]
print(result)
```

`thishasadigit`

Is there a compact way of coding this task?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? It can be made slightly more compact by inlining `m` but that's about it. Matching (`(.*?)\d`) or replacing everything after the first digit (`\d.*`) might be slightly more compact but would IMO be less clean (and probably less performant).

Comment: How do you measure "least amount of code"? Characters? Number of calls? Also, you didn't remove anything here - you don't save the result nor print it (it shows up in REPL only because expressions show up the result's repr)

Comment: `re.match(r"([^\d]*)",s1)[0]`?

Comment: I am uncertain that this is the most proper way to code this in python. It could be, but I do not know. Also, it could be tricky to read for those unfamiliar with re search patterns

Comment: Maybe `re.split('\d', s1)[0]` or `re.sub('\d.*', '', s1)`? This site is not for code golf, though.

Comment: So are you asking how to make the code shorter, more correct, or more understandable/maintainable? That are different requirements with (probably) different answers.

Comment: Note that there is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for feedback about working code and [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) for coding challenges like minimal lines of code, minimal byte count, etc. Stack Overflow might not be the best site for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments shorter code does not always imply better code (although it can be fun to go [golfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)).

That said (with `re` imported and `mystring` having your string), how about this:

```py
result = re.split(r"\d", mystring, maxsplit=1)[0]
```

See https://pynative.com/python-regex-split/ for more information.

Answer (score -2):

If it is just a digit you are trying to find, you probably don't need a regex -

```py
import string
s1 = "thishasadigit4here"
min_digit_index = min(s1.find(_) for _ in string.digits if s1.find(_) > -1)
s1[:min_digit_index]
# 'thishasadigit'
```

All of that can be reduced to a single line -

```py
import string
s1[:min(s1.find(_) for _ in string.digits if s1.find(_) > -1)]
# 'thishasadigit'
```